# Basic substitution

Tags: evaluation, replacement

I am relatively new to *Mathematica*, so I am sure this is basic, but I lack the basic terminology to be able to google it.

How can I make this command work?

```
Plot[x / a, {x, 0, a}] /. {a->10}
```

I would expect this to plot the same line for all values of `a`. But I get

```
Plot::plln: Limiting value a in {Charting`Private`pvar$10408,0,a} is not a machine-sized real number.
```

I understand that `Plot` expects numbers not variables, but what is the correct syntax to resolve this since `a` is ultimately a number?

Comment: I wonder whether *"to google sth"* really should replace *"to look sth up"*? Are we getting paid for that kind of word of mouth advertising - especially for a monopolist? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[{a = 10},
 Plot[
  x/a,
  {x, 0, a}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
Clear[p]
p[a_] := Plot[x/a, {x, 0, a}]
p[10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delay the evaluation of `Plot` with [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
Unevaluated@Plot[x/a, {x, 0, a}] /. {a -> 10}
```

If all occurrences of `a` are not literally present in the `Plot` code, [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) can be used in place of [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
function = x/a;
x = 2;   (* to show that this is ignored in the Plot command *)
Block[{a = 10},
 Plot[function, {x, 0, a}]
 ]
```

The issue to keep in mind is that `Plot` is [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), so that the value for `function` is not substituted (it is said to be "held") before `Plot` is called.  This means, for instance, that is `x` also has a value, it won't be used because `Plot` localizes (via `Block`).

*A note on the second example:*
The definitions of `function` and `x` is pretty bad programming practice.  The order of the definition is crucial, and it's bad to have such a dependency in *Mathematica's* notebook environment in which any cell can be evaluated at any time.  Later if I decide I need to fix the definition of `function`, say `function = 2 x/a`, then the value of `x` will be substituted and `function` will be equal to `4/a` and no longer depend on `x`.  It's not as bad if it's a quick, one-off calculation, but it will still leave your current session with a latent definition of `x`. (Personally, my eyesight has trouble distinguishing *Mathematica's* undefined blue from the defined black on single-letter variables.) If you're writing code that will be reevaluated several times, you're better off making all dependencies functional:

```
function[x_, a_] := x/a
```

It doesn't help with the OP's substitution problem, in which `a` appears in more than just the function, so this or one of the other solutions will be needed for that.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to get your substitution in before Plot evaluates its arguments. Next to defining the `Plot` inside a function with an argument *a* as shown by LouisB you can do the following:

Either

```
plotargs = { x/a, {x,0,a} };
Plot @@ ( plotargs /. a-> 10 )
```

or

```
inactive = Inactivate @ Plot[ x/a, {x,0,a} ];
inactive /. a -> 10 // Activate
```

To make this more general:

```
parameters = Association[
    a -> 10
]; (* could be a whole bunch of parameters... *)

SetAttributes[ withParameters, HoldFirst];
withParameters[ func_ , pars_Association ] := Inactivate[ func ] /. pars // Activate

withParameters[ Plot[ x/a, {x, 0, a}] , parameters ]
```

**Update:**

If you want to pass your function as an argument to `withParameters` it is safest to use [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) also. So:

```
myParametricFunc = Inactivate @ Plot[ x/a, {x,0,a}];
withParameters[ myParametricFunc, parameters]
```

As a word of caution:  As you can see in the documentation, the inactive form is different from the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html). So replacement will work for simple parameters and even options, but not for more complex substitution patters with regard to functional form.